# Manually evaluating logical expressions

Tags: logic, boolean-logic, boolean-expression

I'm not sure if this belongs here, but I was told to evaluate
(00110101 ^ (10010101 v 10100000))

How is my answer suppose to look like?
I was wondering how I would do this?

I'm thinking of treating each of those values as a variable like (a ^ (b v c))
then make a truth table? Is that what I'm suppose to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the stuff in the parentheses first:

```
   10010101
|  10100000
-----------
   101.....
```

Then AND the result with the first number:

```
   00110101
&  101.....
-----------
   001.....
```

Comment: I've never seen bitwise stuff before. I think I understand what to do. I got 00110101 as my answer, is this correct?

Comment: @user1692517: Yep, that's what I got.

Answer (score 0):

For bitwise logic simply evaluate each expression bit-by-bit. Take the first bit of expressions b and c and OR them, then AND them with the first bit of a. Then move to the second bit, etc. You should end up with a bit string of equal length as the starting strings.